# How does Polymer function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, data-binding, polymer-1.0

I have just started using polymer and it is very good so far. And I intent to use it to explore more. But only Question I have is does polymer compile my HTML and pass it through different internal compilers Just like angular ?

What are different stages involved in polymer's data binding, styling and event addition phases ?

How will this help in exporting or publishing My polymer elements for any other web-application without disturbing the existing web-application styles data-bindings ..etc?

Something like

```
<link rel=import href='path/to/my-element.html'>
// ••••••
 //  ••••••
   <my-element attribute=value > 
        </my-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

Polymer does everything at runtime without any build steps. There are tools like [polybuild](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polybuild) for different optimizations like inlining and minification.

Comment: So you mean it does not compile the html or doesnt have any link..bind phases etc..

Comment: You can load the source of previously unknown elements at runtime from a server and add them to the DOM and bindings will be resolved. There are no link..bind phades.